# how to change the color of quicklaunch header in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

find me a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution: Open the site in SharePoint designer, select the used master page and edit that, or edit the css linked to the masterpage.
(Works for one site only)

More robust solution: create a new theme and apply that to your site, the theme can be reused accros multiple sites.

---

If you don't know the css name of the element use the Developer Tools in IE 8 (press `F12`) and select the element you want to style to find out the styles applied to that (and its name)